# How to find find a grouping of upper and lower case characters in a string in python 3

Tags: python, string

I'm working on Python Challenges, and the level I'm on asks us to find a lower case letter surrounded on both sides by exactly three upper case letters. I've written the following code, which seems pretty crude but I feel should work. However, all I get is an empty string.

```
source="Hello there" #the string I have to work with
key=""#where I want to put the characters that fit
for i in source:
    if i==i.lower(): # if it's uppercase
        x=source.index(i) #makes number that's the index of i
        if source[x-1].upper()==source[x-1] and source[x-2]==source[x-2].upper() and source[x-3].upper()==source[x-3]: #checks that the three numbers before it are upper case
            if source[x+1].upper()==source[x+1] and source[x+2].upper()==source[x+2] and source[x+3].upper()==source[x+3]: #checks three numbers after are uppercase
                if source[x+4].lower()==source[x=4] and source[x-4].lower()==source[x-4]: #checks that the fourth numbers are lowercase
                key+=i #adds the character to key
print(key)
```

I know this is really, really messy but I don't understand why it just returns an empty string. If you have any idea what's wrong, or a more efficient way to do it, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: "If If you have any idea what's wrong, or a **more efficient way** to do it, I would really appreciate it"  Use regex, `[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}`

Comment: Try the [`isupper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) and [`islower`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) methods

Answer (score 0):

This is far, far easier with a regular expression.

```
re.findall(r'(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}([a-z])(?=[A-Z]{3}(?:\Z|[^A-Z]))', text)
```

Here's how it works:

- `(?<![A-Z])` is a *negative lookbehind assertion* which makes sure that we are not preceded by an upper-case letter.
- `[A-Z]{3}` is three upper-case letters.
- `([a-z])` is the lower-case letter we are looking for.
- `(?=[A-Z]{3}(?:\Z|[^A-Z]))` is a *lookahead assertion* that makes sure we are followed by three upper-case letters but not four.

You will probably need to change the grouping depending on what you actually want to find.  This finds the lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) method with a `keyfunc` to distinguish lowercase from capital letters.

First you need a helper function to refactor the check logic:

```
def check(subseq):
    return (subseq[0][0] and len(subseq[0][1]) == 3
            and len(subseq[1][1]) == 1
            and len(subseq[2][1]) == 3)
```

Then group up and check:

```
def findNeedle(mystr):
    seq = [(k,list(g)) for k,g in groupby(mystr, str.isupper)]
    for i in range(len(seq) - 2):
        if check(seq[i:i+3]):
            return seq[i+1][1][0]
```

Inspect `seq` in the interpreter to see how this works, it should be very clear.

**Edit:** Some typos, I didn't test the code.

Now a test:

```
>>> findNeedle("Hello there HELxOTHere")
'x'
```